# SQL Join, include rows from table a with no match in table b

Tags: mysql, sql, join, inner-join

```
SELECT orders.*
  FROM orders
  JOIN order_rows 
  ON orders.id = order_rows.order_id 
  WHERE order_rows.quant <> order_rows.quant_fulfilled 
  GROUP BY orders.id 
  ORDER BY orders.id DESC
```

How do I include rows that have no corresponding order_row entries (which would be an order that has no items in it yet)?

There will only be a couple empty orders at a given time so I would use a separate query if the best answer to this is going to significantly decrease performance. But I was hoping to include them in this query so they are sorted by orders.id along with the rest. I don't want to double query time just to include the 1-3 orders that have no items.

Comment: Have you tried using `LEFT JOIN` instead of your INNER JOIN?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to select from two tables in MySQL even if not all rows in one table have corespondents in the other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3969452/how-to-select-from-two-tables-in-mysql-even-if-not-all-rows-in-one-table-have-co)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Simply use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `JOIN`. You'll obtain all rows of orders.

```
SELECT orders.*
FROM orders
LEFT JOIN order_rows 
  ON orders.id = order_rows.order_id
 AND order_rows.quant <> order_rows.quant_fulfilled 
GROUP BY orders.id 
ORDER BY orders.id DESC
```

Comment: wouldn't it be better to do `WHERE oder_rows.id IS NULL` instead of `oder_row.quants`?