# Return "null" value if no record for date

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm starting a query where i want to get all records between a time range. For Example:

```
select * from table where date between '2017-01-01' and '2017-01-31'
```

returns 31 records. But if there is no record for '2017-01-02' it will return 30 records.

Is it possible that for the missing date the query returns a null record to get 31 records too?

Data/Table

```
2017-01-01 | value1 | value2
2017-01-03 | value3 | value3
```

The select query should return

```
2017-01-01 | value1 | value2
null       | null   | null
2017-01-03 | value3 | value3
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to select from two tables in MySQL even if not all rows in one table have corespondents in the other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3969452/how-to-select-from-two-tables-in-mysql-even-if-not-all-rows-in-one-table-have-co)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a `left join`.  This is easy in Postgres, using `generate_series()`:

```
select g.dte, t.col1, . . .
from generate_series('2017-01-1'::timestamp, '2017-01-31'::timestamp, interval '1 day') g(dte) left join
     table t
     on g.dte = t.date;
```