# Correct JOIN in query

Tags: mysql, sql, join

In the low query, how do I display all records in the "users" table?
Currently only those with a sales record are being displayed

```
    SELECT
    d.operator_id as num_carteira,
    u.name_carteira as Carteira,
    sum(d.`value`) AS Valor,
    sum(d.`quantity`) AS Qtde
    FROM daily_productivity d
    RIGHT JOIN product p
    ON d.product_id = p.id
    RIGHT JOIN `user` u
    ON d.operator_id = u.id
    WHERE YEAR(date) = 2019 AND MONTH(date) = 06 AND d.daily_productivity_status_id = 2 AND p.mobilizador_id = 1 AND u.role_id = 6 
    ORDER BY u.name_carteira
```

Comment: (1) Tag your question with the database you are using.  (2) Identify the table where `date` comes from.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mcve]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) PS What does "display all records in the "users" table" mean? Display them how? Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. Say enough that someone could go away & come back with a solution. Given examples.

Comment: Learn what LEFT JOIN ON returns: INNER JOIN ON rows UNION ALL unmatched left table rows extended by NULLs. Always know what INNER JOIN you want as part of an OUTER JOIN.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to select from two tables in MySQL even if not all rows in one table have corespondents in the other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3969452/how-to-select-from-two-tables-in-mysql-even-if-not-all-rows-in-one-table-have-co)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `left join`s and put the table where you want to keep all the rows first -- that would be `user`.  Conditions on this table can be filtered in the `where` clause.

Conditions on all other tables should go in the `on` clause:

```
SELECT d.operator_id as num_carteira, u.name_carteira as Carteira,
       sum(d.`value`) AS Valor, sum(d.`quantity`) AS Qtde
FROM user u LEFT JOIN
     daily_productivity d
     ON d.operator_id = u.id AND
        d.date >= '2019-06-01' AND
        d.date < '2019-07-01' AND
        d.daily_productivity_status_id = 2 LEFT JOIN
     product p
     ON d.product_id = p.id AND p.mobilizador_id = 1
WHERE u.role_id = 6 
GROUP BY d.operator_id, u.name_carteira 
ORDER BY u.name_carteira;
```

This guesses that `date` comes from the `daily_productivity` table.

Note that I changed the date logic so it is more index-compatible.  I would also recommend using `u.id` rather than `d.operator_id` in the `SELECT` because the latter could be `NULL`.

If you do, indeed, want all users in `user` then remove the `where` clause.

Comment: With this SQL appeared only 1 record, of a user.

Comment: @gugoan . . . The query *should* have returned an error -- as yours should as well.  It uses aggregation functions with no `GROUP BY`.  You must be using an old version of MySQL.

Comment: I'm using the version: 5.5.45 - MySQL Community Server

Comment: I can not upgrade to the server, would I have any other alternative?

Comment: @gugoan . . . I fixed the query.  I'm just saying that an error *should* be generated and would be in the more recent versions of MySQL (using the default settings).

Comment: Now viewing all users (manager) correctly. But the values do not beat, he is not considering the condition of the product: ON d.product_id = p.id AND p.mobilizador_id = 1

Comment: @gugoan . . . If you want *all* users, then the filtering is in the `ON` clause with outer joins.  If you want to limit the products, you can use inner joins.

Answer (score 2):

You should not use left / right joined  tables columns in where clause  you should add these condition to the related  ON clause

```
    SELECT
    d.operator_id as num_carteira,
    u.name_carteira as Carteira,
    sum(d.`value`) AS Valor,
    sum(d.`quantity`) AS Qtde
    FROM daily_productivity d
    LEFT  JOIN product p  ON d.product_id = p.id AND  p.mobilizador_id = 1 
    LEFT JOIN `user` u   ON d.operator_id = u.id AND  u.role_id = 6 
    WHERE YEAR(date) = 2019 AND MONTH(date) = 06 AND d.daily_productivity_status_id = 2 
    ORDER BY u.name_carteira
```

and you should use also proper  group  by

```
    SELECT
    d.operator_id as num_carteira,
    u.name_carteira as Carteira,
    sum(d.`value`) AS Valor,
    sum(d.`quantity`) AS Qtde
    FROM daily_productivity d
    LEFT  JOIN product p  ON d.product_id = p.id AND  p.mobilizador_id = 1 
    LEFT JOIN `user` u   ON d.operator_id = u.id AND  u.role_id = 6 
    WHERE YEAR(date) = 2019 AND MONTH(date) = 06 AND d.daily_productivity_status_id = 2 
    GROUP BY d.operator_id as num_carteira,  u.name_carteira as Carteira,
    ORDER BY u.name_carteira
```

the use of aggregation function without group by in most db  (and for particular db version) is not allowed  and ca raise error