# How Do I Write a MySQL Query that Includes a row that Has Null Data?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, inner-join, where-clause

Below is a description of the scenario I'm trying to solve.

I have two tables. One table called displays is shown below.

```
id(INT) name(VARCHAR) start_date(DATE) end_Date(DATE) person_id(INT)
5       Whales        2019-01-01       2019-05-31     7
19      Universe      2019-02-01       2019-03-31     13
25      Grizzlies     2019-03-01       2019-06-30     7 
46      Homosapiens?  2019-07-01       2019-09-31     13
```

The other table called people is shown below.

```
id(INT) name(VARCHAR) background(TEXT)
7       Ron Swanson   Nonconformist
13      Tom Haverford Hustler
71      Andy Dwyer    Goofball
```

I'm looking to write a SQL query that finds all the names of all displays and the names of the people associated with the displays. If a display does not have a person, the display should not be in the result. Even if a person does not have a display, the person's name should be present in the final result. The correct query should show the following results (see table below).

```
Ron Swanson   Whales
Tom Haverford Universe
Ron Swanson   Grizzlies
Tom Haverford Homosapiens?
Andy Dwyer
```

The query I've come up with is

```
SELECT p.name, d.name from displays d, people p WHERE d.person_id = p.id;
```

Which gets the right result minus Andy Dwyer. I'm stumped on how to include Andy Dwyer, what am I missing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to select from two tables in MySQL even if not all rows in one table have corespondents in the other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3969452/how-to-select-from-two-tables-in-mysql-even-if-not-all-rows-in-one-table-have-co)

Comment: This is a faq. Before considering posting please read the manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Refect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a `LEFT JOIN` from `people` to `displays`:

```
SELECT p.name, d.name
FROM people p
LEFT JOIN displays d ON d.person_id = p.id
```

Output (for your sample data)

```
name            name
Ron Swanson     Whales
Tom Haverford   Universe
Ron Swanson     Grizzlies
Tom Haverford   Homosapiens?
Andy Dwyer      (null)
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/89da74/1)