# MySQL - Daily overview only shows current bookings rather than all

Tags: mysql, join, select, view

I'm trying to get a view where I can select a specific day and it will return a list of ALL rooms with the current days breakdown.

Currently it shows the daily overview for a specific day but lacks showing rooms which DONT have bookings for the day selected?

(I need to display the daily overview for all rooms even without bookings)

How do I change this so it will show ALL rooms even when there is not a booking for the specific room on that day as well as rooms that do?

***Current display (for 2019-11-24):***

```
SELECT * FROM `Daily Overview` WHERE '2019-11-24' >= StartDate AND '2019-11-24' <= EndDate;

3   Family  2   2019-11-24  2019-11-28  4   2   2,3 Ahri,Blitz
4   Dual    1   2019-11-22  2019-11-25  2   1   1   Aatrox
```

**Desired output:**

```
1
2
3   Family  2   2019-11-24  2019-11-28  4   2   2,3 Ahri,Blitz
4   Dual    1   2019-11-22  2019-11-25  2   1   1   Aatrox
5
6
8
9
10
```

***View script:***

```
CREATE VIEW `Daily Overview` AS
SELECT ROOMINFO.ID as Room, ROOMINFO.`Type`,
    BOOKROOM.Ref as Ref,
    BOOK.Start_Date as StartDate,
    BOOK.End_Date as EndDate
FROM ROOMINFO
JOIN BOOKROOM ON ROOMINFO.ID = BOOKROOM.ID
JOIN BOOK ON ROOMINFO.ID AND BOOK.Ref = BOOKROOM.Ref
GROUP BY ROOMINFO.ID, ROOMINFO.`Type`, ROOMINFO.Max, Ref;
```

***table data & structure script:***

```
CREATE SCHEMA CATTERY2;
USE CATTERY2;

CREATE TABLE BOOK( Ref INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, Start_Date DATE NOT NULL, End_Date DATE NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(Ref));
CREATE TABLE ROOMINFO( ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,`Type` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL, Max TINYINT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(ID));
CREATE TABLE BOOKROOM( Ref INT NOT NULL, ID INT NOT NULL, FOREIGN KEY (Ref) REFERENCES BOOK(Ref), FOREIGN KEY (ID) REFERENCES ROOMINFO(ID));

INSERT INTO BOOK(Start_Date, End_Date) VALUES   
("2019-11-22", "2019-11-25"), ("2019-11-24", "2019-11-28");

INSERT INTO ROOMINFO (ID, `Type`,Max) VALUES
(1, "Family", 4), (2, "Family", 4), (3, "Family", 4), (4, "Dual", 2),
(5, "Dual", 2),   (6, "Dual", 2), (7, "Dual", 2),   (8, "Dual", 2),
(9, "Dual", 2),   (10, "Dual", 2);

INSERT INTO BOOKROOM( Ref, ID ) VALUES
    (1, 4), (2, 3);
```

Comment: Please show your desired output & corresponding input for minimal representative data & query. [mre] Not just some big query that doesn't do what you want or for tens of rows of data.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to select from two tables in MySQL even if not all rows in one table have corespondents in the other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3969452/how-to-select-from-two-tables-in-mysql-even-if-not-all-rows-in-one-table-have-co)

Comment: `roominfo.id and book.ref = bookroom.ref` Eh?

Comment: Also, it's seriously confusing to use `id` as a foreign key. If you must use `id`, then at least name the foreing key `booking_id` or `room_id` or whatever. Otherwsie, wev'e no chance

Comment: This is a faq. Before considering posting please read the manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Comment: @philipxy i specified the desired output but did not show the exact log, i have updated the question to include the specific desired output and removed unneeded data. I will also look at the link you provided

Comment: @Strawberry there is no booking ID, the booking primary key is Ref, the primary key for a room is ID, the primary key for a cat is Chip_ID

Comment: See how confusing it is

Comment: That seems like a lot of code for asking about a basic step. In general: Give the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. When you get a result that you don't expect, find out what your misunderstanding is.--Isolate the first erroneous subexpression & its input & output. In procedural programs give input to give the first point in execution that gives a state you don't expect. (Debugging absolute fundamentals.) PS Please clarify via edits, not comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following. Note that I've modified your structure slightly to aid comprehension:

```
DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS cattery2;

CREATE SCHEMA CATTERY2;
USE CATTERY2;

CREATE TABLE cats
(cat_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,name VARCHAR(30) 
,sex CHAR(1) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE bookings
(booking_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,start_Date DATE NOT NULL
,end_date DATE NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE rooms
(room_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,capacity TINYINT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE room_booking
(room_id INT NOT NULL
,booking_id INT NOT NULL
,PRIMARY KEY(room_id,booking_id)
);

CREATE TABLE cat_booking
(cat_id INT NOT NULL
,booking_id INT NOT NULL
,PRIMARY KEY(cat_id,booking_id)
);  

INSERT INTO bookings(start_date, end_date) VALUES   
("2019-11-22", "2019-11-25"), 
("2019-11-24", "2019-11-28"), 
("2019-12-01", "2019-12-02"), 
("2019-12-01", "2019-12-06"),
("2019-12-02", "2019-12-03"), 
("2019-12-04", "2019-12-10"), 
("2019-12-04", "2019-12-10"), 
("2019-12-05", "2019-12-13"),
("2019-12-16", "2019-12-19"), 
("2019-12-26", "2019-12-28"), 
("2019-12-26", "2020-01-01"), 
("2019-12-28", "2020-01-02"),
("2019-12-31", "2020-01-05"), 
("2020-01-03", "2020-01-08"), 
("2020-01-05", "2020-01-11"), 
("2020-01-06", "2020-01-09"),
("2020-01-06", "2020-01-11"), 
("2020-01-08", "2020-01-18"), 
("2020-01-11", "2020-01-15"), 
("2020-01-15", "2020-01-17"),
("2020-01-15", "2020-01-18");

INSERT INTO rooms (room_id,capacity) VALUES
( 1,4), 
( 2,4), 
( 3,4), 
( 4,2),
( 5,2),   
( 6,2), 
( 7,2),   
( 8,2),
( 9,2),
(10,2);

INSERT INTO room_booking (booking_id,room_id) VALUES
( 1,  4), 
( 2,  3), 
( 3,  4), 
( 4,  5),
( 5,  6), 
( 6,  7), 
( 7,  3), 
( 8,  2),
( 9,  1), 
(10,  8), 
(11,  3),
(12,  9),
(13,  2),
(14, 10), 
(15,  4),
(16,  5),
(17,  6),
(18,  7),
(19,  2),
(20,  1),
(21, 10);

INSERT INTO cats (name,sex) VALUES
('Aatrox', 'm'), 
('Ahri', 'f'), 
('Blitz', 'm'), 
('Curley', 'm'),
('Mandy', 'm'), 
('Nami', 'f'), 
('Kog', 'm'), 
('Caitlyn', 'f'),
('Barney', 'm'), 
('Gnar', 'm'), 
('Charley', 'f'), 
('Bundy', 'm'),
('Ringo', 'm'), 
('Smiley', 'm'), 
('Bentley', 'f'), 
('Barney', 'm'),
('Yuumi', 'f'), 
('Rammus', 'm'), 
('Viktor', 'm'), 
('Xerath', 'm'),
('Azir', 'm'), 
('Reginald', 'm'), 
('Harry', 'm'), 
('Indie', 'f'),
('Dotty', 'f'), 
('Wesley', 'm'), 
('Karma', 'f'), 
('Nami', 'f'),
('Nautalus', 'm'), 
('Tristy', 'f'), 
('Kaisa', 'f'), 
('Baron', 'm'),
('Braum', 'm'), 
('Alistar', 'm'), 
('Ahri', 'f');

INSERT INTO cat_booking(booking_id,cat_id) VALUES
 ( 1,  1), 
 ( 2,  2), 
 ( 2,  3), 
 ( 3,  1),
 ( 4,  2), 
 ( 5,  3), 
 ( 5,  4), 
 ( 6,  5),
 ( 7,  6), 
 ( 7,  7),  
 ( 7,  8), 
 ( 8,  9),
 ( 8, 10), 
 ( 8, 11), 
 ( 9, 12), 
 ( 9, 13),
 ( 9, 14), 
 (10, 15), 
 (11, 16), 
 (11, 17),
 (11, 18), 
 (12, 19), 
 (12, 20), 
 (13, 21),
 (13, 22), 
 (13, 23), 
 (14, 24), 
 (14, 25),
 (15, 26), 
 (16, 27), 
 (16, 28), 
 (17, 29),
 (18, 30), 
 (19, 31), 
 (19, 32), 
 (20, 33),
 (20, 34), 
 (21, 35);
```

And the query...

```
SELECT DISTINCT r.room_id
              , r.capacity
              , x.booking_id
              , x.start_date
              , x.end_date
           FROM rooms r 
           LEFT
           JOIN 
              ( SELECT b.booking_id
                     , b.start_date
                     , b.end_date
                     , rb.room_id
                  FROM bookings b
                  JOIN room_booking rb 
                    ON rb.booking_id = b.booking_id
                 WHERE '2019-11-24' BETWEEN b.start_date AND b.end_date
              ) x
             ON x.room_id = r.room_id
          ORDER
             BY r.room_id
              , r.capacity
              , x.start_date
              , x.booking_id;

   +---------+----------+------------+------------+------------+
   | room_id | capacity | booking_id | start_date | end_date   |
   +---------+----------+------------+------------+------------+
   |       1 |        4 |       NULL | NULL       | NULL       |
   |       2 |        4 |       NULL | NULL       | NULL       |
   |       3 |        4 |          2 | 2019-11-24 | 2019-11-28 |
   |       4 |        2 |          1 | 2019-11-22 | 2019-11-25 |
   |       5 |        2 |       NULL | NULL       | NULL       |
   |       6 |        2 |       NULL | NULL       | NULL       |
   |       7 |        2 |       NULL | NULL       | NULL       |
   |       8 |        2 |       NULL | NULL       | NULL       |
   |       9 |        2 |       NULL | NULL       | NULL       |
   |      10 |        2 |       NULL | NULL       | NULL       |
   +---------+----------+------------+------------+------------+
```

Also, note that there's no VIEW here. This is deliberate. Queries against VIEWS in MySQL have limited access to underlying indexes, making them (in my VIEW) almost useless.

Comment: I see what you mean by difficult to understand when used in this context now, but overall does everything i needed to query, appreciate the time and effort :)