# Show daily count of zero when there are no records for a "group"

Tags: sql, rdbms

I'm doing a daily count of errors grouped by type.  How would I make Day 2 show error2 with zero if there are no records with error2 on day 2?

Day 1

```
Type   Count
error1   5
error2   6
error3   1
```

Day 2

```
type   Count
error1   6
error3   2
```

Comment: Do you have a table that have all your types? Can you share some data and a SQL that you use to get the data that you're getting here?

Comment: OUTER JOIN a help table/cte returning all different errors.

Comment: if the  type is static like there are only 3 errors type then you can use case statemen like `select (CASE WHEN type = 'error1' THEN  count ELSE 0 END),(CASE WHEN type = 'error2' THEN  count ELSE 0 END),(CASE WHEN type = 'error3' THEN  count ELSE 0 END) FROM table group by type, date`.

Comment: OK nice, since I don't have a help table containing all the errors, should I make one? I don't think it is ideal to query the entire table for distinct errors so a saved table would avoid that.

Comment: I think base data is a good idea for most relational databases. Use an id as one column and the name of the error as another column. Then use the that id in your table with a foreign key constraint. You should probably update your Question to include the RDBMS too.

Comment: @jarlh -- left join is what you mean... outer join can lead to some real problems.

Comment: @Hogan, actually this is one of the rare cases I'd do a RIGHT OUTER JOIN. For once they make sense here. A LEFT OUTER JOIN would be fine too.

Comment: @jarlh -- no idea if it is true of this data, but in many cases using an outer will be slower and often leads to bugs

Comment: @Hogan Left join is left outer join & right join is right outer join. When you said "outer join" did you mean full join aka full outer join? Re "some real problems" & "in many cases using an outer will be slower and often leads to bugs", that is indefensible. It's like saying addition is OK but subtraction can have those problems.

Comment: This is a faq. Before considering posting please read your textbook and/or manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to select from two tables in MySQL even if not all rows in one table have corespondents in the other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3969452/how-to-select-from-two-tables-in-mysql-even-if-not-all-rows-in-one-table-have-co)

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. Show what relevant parts you are able to do & explain re being stuck.

Comment: The rdbms you should have added seems to be sql-server (the syntax of "dbo." from your answer indicates that). Not the literal tag "rdbms". SQL syntax often depends on what database you're using.

Comment: @philipxy -- yes I think maybe there is some terminalolgy confusion -- left joins, right joins and full outer joins -- when I say an outer join I mean a full outer join -- I don't say left outer join.  I guess you could call it a left outer join but no one has called them that in 20 years in my experience.

Comment: @Hogan Read any introduction to SQL joins. OUTER is a noise/optiional keyword, ie optional in the 3 outer joins, and is not used by itself for anything else but to refer to all 3.

Answer (score 1):

You select the distinct list of types from the table and then left join back to that.

Notes, I assume type is the column you want to count.
I assume there is a distinct column called ID

```
SELECT
  BASE_VALUES.TYPE, COUNT(TABLEYOUDIDNOTSAY.ID) AS COUNT
FROM (
   SELECT DISTINCT TYPE FROM TABLEYOUDIDNOTSAY
) AS BASE_VALUES
LEFT JOIN TABLEYOUDIDNOTSAY ON TABLEYOUDIDNOTSAY.TYPE = BASE_VALUES.TYPE
WHERE DAY = 'SOMEDAY'
GROUP BY BASE_VALUES.TYPE
```

Comment: The where needed to be an and for all of my base_value.type to show.  Some nuance of the left joins and accounting for nulls.

Comment: The where being an and does not make sense to me --- you said you wanted to show only data for one day.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to make a table by selecting into dbo.authentication_erros and doing an outer join from it solved by problem.  Thanks- P

Comment: outer joins are bad idea.  You probably want a left join.

Comment: Why can't I approve an answer from an above comment by jarlh

Comment: A comment is not an answer.

Comment: Just to make everything clear here, a `LEFT JOIN`/`LEFT OUTER JOIN` is an outer join, a `RIGHT JOIN`/`RIGHT OUTER JOIN` is an outer join, and finally - a `FULL JOIN`/`FULL OUTER JOIN` is an outer join. The `OUTER` keyword is optional in all three versions.