# MySQL: Show all data from one query and join data from another query where it matches

Tags: mysql, sql, join, select

Trying to understand SQL more as part of a POC I'm working on and have hit a snag. I have two select queries (shown below) and I want to combine these into a single query that:

1. Shows all of the results of query one
2. Joins the result of query two if the category column matches.
3. Provides a default of 0 if there is no match

Query one:

```
SELECT activityId, location, category, activityScore FROM activities WHERE location = "manchester";
```

Query two:

```
SELECT userId, category, userScore FROM userscore s WHERE userId = "32976428";
```

Expected Output:
The resulting query should show all activities in "manchester" along with the associated userScore if the specified use has one that matches that category. If there is no userscore then 0 should be returned instead.

Thanks for any help.

Carl

Comment: please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query and edit your question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to select from two tables in MySQL even if not all rows in one table have corespondents in the other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3969452/how-to-select-from-two-tables-in-mysql-even-if-not-all-rows-in-one-table-have-co)

Comment: This is a faq. Before considering posting please read your textbook and/or manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need a LEFT JOIN on your userscore table

```
SELECT a.activityId, a.location, a.category, a.activityScore,
       s.userId, ISNULL(s.userScore,0) as userScore  
FROM activities a
LEFT JOIN userscore s ON s.category = a.category AND s.userId = "32976428"
WHERE a.location = "manchester";
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Only change is that ISNULL should be IFNULL.