# GroupBy clause removing all null column values

Tags: mysql, join, select, group-by, inner-join

I have written the following query wherein I am usig groupby clause on `server` column

```
select s.server, MAX(s.ipAddress) as ipAddress, 
        MAX(r.stacks->>"$[0].name") as stackName,
        MAX(a.aMessage) as aMessage
        from environments e
        inner join servers s
            on e.objectId  = s.environmentId
        inner join resources r
            on e.objectId  = r.environmentId     
        inner join audits a
            on a.id  = (select max(a.id) from audits a where a.logObjId = s.cAudit)  
        WHERE dateSubmitted BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 90 DAY AND NOW()
        Group by s.server
        ORDER BY dateSubmitted;
```

Howerver, `server` column may have `NULL` values with a valid `ipAddress` and `stackName`.

How to modify the query so that all `NULL` `server` column values are not missed out.

Expected Sample Data:

```
server  ipAddress   stackName   aMessage
NULL    NULL    Stack A Searching for IP pool
NULL    NULL    Stack B Message XYZ
NULL    NULL    Stack A Message ABC
```

Comment: I suspect it's your inner joins that are removing the nulls, not your group by. Consider switching those to `LEFT OUTER JOIN` instead.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Comment: Agree with @philipxy in this case.  Sample data would go a long way here, and since you have so many tables involved, sample data might be absolutely necessary to make your question reproducible.

Comment: Presumably your server nulls appear in the same rows as nulls in a column mentioned in an inner join equality, but for those equalities to be true & a row to be in the join, the columns must be non-null.

Comment: I have added the sample data. Please help getting updated query now. Thanks

Comment: Where? There are 4 tables and there is no sample data for them. What you need to do is to "dumb it down" (go one join at a time) and test it as you go...

Comment: The other columns have text data similar to `aMessage` and `stackName`

Comment: You have clearly not acted on all my comment. Why did you comment? (Rhetorical.) PS Please clarify via edits, not comments.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to select from two tables in MySQL even if not all rows in one table have corespondents in the other?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3969452/3404097) Please before considering posting read your textbook and/or manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the `INNER JOIN` used to `JOIN` the table makes `NULL` value to removed from the result. So just modified the query. Try this one and see if you are able to see all the data of `Server` table so that `NULL` data also will come for `Server` column.

```
select s.server, MAX(s.ipAddress) as ipAddress, 
            MAX(r.stacks->>"$[0].name") as stackName,
            MAX(a.aMessage) as aMessage
            from servers s
            left join environments e
                on e.objectId  = s.environmentId
            left join resources r
                on e.objectId  = r.environmentId     
            left join audits a
                on a.id  = (select max(a.id) from audits a where a.logObjId = s.cAudit)  
            WHERE dateSubmitted BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 90 DAY AND NOW()
            Group by s.server
            ORDER BY dateSubmitted;
```

Comment: This is still not working as I see only one row with `server` as `NULL`