# mysql left join with group_concat - only shows a single result

Tags: mysql, sql, string, date, join

So I am not sure if I am taking the right approach but here is what I am after:
I need to get all the records from table A

Then join on table B and concatenate all the values that match a specific ID from Table.

What I am noticing with my query below, is that I only get results where there is a record in Table B - I want to be able to display a NULL value in my result set if there is no corresponding value in Table A

```
SELECT Account.AccountID, AccountOpenedDate, AccountStatus, GROUP_CONCAT(Expense.ExpenseType SEPARATOR ':') AS Expense FROM Account
    JOIN Expense ON Account.AccountID=Expense.AccountID
    GROUP BY MONTH(DATE(AccountOpenedDate)), Account.AccountID
    ORDER BY Account.AccountID ASC;
```

I want to return all accounts and account status and opened date
Then if Expense has a value for that row display those values concatenated with ":" as a separator.

I only seem to get results where a record exists in both tables.

Comment: Vaguely repeating in prose what wrong code does is not a clear way to say what you want. Say how desired output is a function of input. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. When giving a business relation(ship)/association or table (base or query result), say what a row in it states about the business situation in terms of its column values.
PS  [How to select from two tables in MySQL even if not all rows in one table have corespondents in the other?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3969452/3404097)

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are describing a `left join`:

```
select 
    a.accountID, 
    a.accountOpenedDate, 
    a.accountStatus, 
    group_concat(e.expenseType separator ':') as expense 
from account a
left join expense e on e.accountID = a.accountID
group by a.accountID
order by a.accountID
```

I also don't see the point for expression `MONTH(DATE(AccountOpenedDate))` in the `GROUP BY` clause: you seem to want one row per account, so this seems irrelevant.

The above query works under the assumption that `accountID` is the primary key of table `account`: other columns from the same column are functionaly dependent on the primary key, so you do not need to list them in the `group by` clause. You could also write this as:

```
select 
    a.accountID, 
    a.accountOpenedDate, 
    a.accountStatus, 
    group_concat(e.expenseType separator ':') as expense 
from account a
left join expense e on e.accountID = a.accountID
group by a.accountID, a.accountOpenedDate, a.accountStatus
order by a.accountID
```

Side notes:

- table aliases make the query easier to write and read
- in a multi-table query, all columns should be qualified (prefixed) with the (alias of the) table they belong to

Comment: Perfect this is what I was looking for.