# MySql Join and count number of records

Tags: mysql, sql, join, count

I have two tables
**tbl_groups:**

```
id |   name        
----------------
 1 | BSCS
 2 | BSIT
 3 | BBA
```

**tbl_students:**

```
id |     name     | group_id
-------------------------------
 1 | Student Name |     1 
 2 | Student 2    |     1
 3 | Student 3    |     2
```

I want to show groups details: group name and number of students in a particular group,

I am using this query but it shows groups that has students. it does not show group with 0 students.

```
select tb2.id, tb2.name, count(*) from tbl_students tb1 JOIN tbl_groups tb2 ON tb1.group_id = tb2.id
```

How do I show all groups, please give me some idea

**EDIT:**
if I use above query I get following result:

```
id |     name     | count(*)
-------------------------------
 1 | Student Name |     2
 2 | BSIT         |     1
```

(it doest show 3rd group because there are 0 students, I want to show this groups also).

Comment: mind to share expected result?

Comment: a left join between groups to students would do

Comment: i have edited question please have a look

Comment: things to note: 1/ you dont have `created_by` in `tbl_groups`. 2/ you dont have `class_id` in `tbl_students`, instead you have `id`

Comment: @AhmedSaeed check @Jorge's answer. it should work. assuming you have typo in the expected result where `Student Name` should be `BSCS`

Comment: @boyke i have edited question, now check

Comment: check @JorgeCampos answer. and the reference as well about Join/Left/Right etc. will be useful for you in the future

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to select from two tables in MySQL even if not all rows in one table have corespondents in the other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3969452/how-to-select-from-two-tables-in-mysql-even-if-not-all-rows-in-one-table-have-co)

Answer (score 3):

Just use a left join:

```
select tb2.id, tb2.name, count(tb1.id) as no_std 
  from tbl_groups tb2
        LEFT JOIN tbl_students tb1 ON tb2.id = tb1.group_id
group by tb2.id, tb2.name
```

See it working live here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2282a3/5

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html for reference . for visual https://cdn.educba.com/academy/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/joins-in-mysql-1.png

Comment: This doesn't produce correct output. I get 3,BBA,1 for the last record, but there are 0 students in group 3. Changing count(*) to count(tb1.id) produces the correct output.

Comment: @BoykeFerdinandes I'm well aware of that graph. The only mistake I made on the query is the one Michael pointed out. Since I'm left joining groups with students the `count(*)` will count the occurrences related to groups when it should only count students so `count(tb1.id)` works fine.

Comment: @MichaelRuth You are right I explained why in my previous comment. Thank you. I will update the answer.

Comment: @BoykeFerdinandes I see that you added the reference for OP. Thanks for that. I originally thought it was for me :)

Comment: @JorgeCampos hahaha,, yes it is for OP,, he also has many typos in his original query

Answer (score 2):

I would just use a correlated subquery to get the count of students in each group, like so:

```
select 
    g.*,
    (select count(*) from tbl_students s where s.group_id = g.id) no_students
from tbl_groups g
```

This does not filter out groups that have no students (it will give a count of `0` instead). And with an index on `tbl_students(group_id)`, this should be as efficient as it gets (this index is already there if you set up a foreign key constraint on that column - as you should have).