# Correct way to join two tables without a common key, and keep a null value when there is no match

Tags: sql, join, google-bigquery, conditional-statements

I am new to sql and realize this may not be rocket science but I have two tables, the first one with a variable title_name from which I want to extract the theme(cannot use regex as the position varies) and a second table which is a lookup table with the correct correspondance.

**Table_1**

title_name (example: uk-book-heroicfantasy-language)

**Table_2**

theme_old (example: heroicfantasy)

theme_new (example: fantasy)

This is what i have come up with so far, but this query only keeps the rows with a match.
How can I say I want a '(not set)' value for theme_new when there is no match?

```
select
 theme_new,
from Table_1, Table_2
where title_name like concat('%',theme_old ,'%')
```

I would very much appreciate any help, none of the approaches I have tried have worked so far.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to select from two tables in MySQL even if not all rows in one table have corespondents in the other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3969452/how-to-select-from-two-tables-in-mysql-even-if-not-all-rows-in-one-table-have-co)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use a [CASE](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_case.asp).

Something like this;

```
select
CASE 
    WHEN title_name like concat('%',theme_old ,'%') THEN theme_new 
    ELSE '(not set)' 
END
from Table_1, Table_2
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You want a `left join`:

```
select theme_new
from Table_1 t1 left join
     Table_2
     on t2.title_name like concat('%', t2.theme_old , '%')
```

That said, I'm not sure if BigQuery supports this syntax.

You may need to use:

```
select t1.title_name, array_agg(theme_new ignore nulls)
from (select t1.title_name, theme_new,
      from Table_1 t1 cross join
           Table_2
      where t2.title_name like concat('%', t2.theme_old , '%')
      union all
      select t1.title_name, null
      from table_1 t1
     ) t1
group by t1.title_name;
```

Comment: Thank you so much, the first option did not work indeed with bq.

Comment: @Thaid . . . Did the second?  Outer joins with inequality conditions are tricky in BQ.