# Create SQL query that lists certain data whether it exists or not

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, left-join

I'm trying to create a query that lists certain items whether or not they appear in the database.  So let's say I have a database that lists the inventory of fruit, and contains this:

```
Fruit     Amount
Apples    5
Bananas   8
Oranges   9
```

But I want to return a result that checks for all my types of fruit, and returns 0 if it can't find them.

```
Fruit     Amount
Apples    5
Apricots  0
Bananas   8
Grapes    0
Oranges   9
```

I'm using SQL Server 2008.

This is my first question here on stackoverflow so forgive me if I've done anything wrong.  I've tried using "Select into" a temp table but can't figure out how to use select into while also checking "If exists".

Any help would be much appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Hint : Left Join with coalesce(Amount,0)

Comment: Left Join using a table with all those fruits

Comment: Is there a table with all the types of fruit?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to select from two tables in MySQL even if not all rows in one table have corespondents in the other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3969452/how-to-select-from-two-tables-in-mysql-even-if-not-all-rows-in-one-table-have-co)

Comment: This is a faq. Please before considering posting read your textbook and/or manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Answer (score 0):

You can enumerate the possible values in a derived table, then bring the original table with a `left join`, and finally aggregate and count:

```
select f.fruit, count(t.fruit) amount
from (values ('Apples'), ('Abricots'), ('Bananas'), ('Grape'), ('Oranges')) as f(fruit)
left join mytable t on t.fruit = f.fruit
group by f.fruit
```

In a real life situation, you would have a referrential table that stores all possible values, say `all_fruits`, which would avoid the need for `values()`:

```
select f.fruit, count(t.fruit) amount
from all_fruits f
left join mytable t on t.fruit = f.fruit
group by f.fruit
```