# Creating a grouped, aggregated, uniquely ordered query that reports 0s

Tags: sql, sql-order-by, self-join

I am trying to design a few queries for my non-technical colleagues to automatically retrieve a set of data about registrations in precisely the format that they need.

Currently I use the simple

```
SELECT Faculty, COUNT(*) 
FROM Registrations 
GROUP BY Faculty
```

The results of this are a list of faculties and the current registrations.

The problem with this is that it will not list any faculty group that has 0 registrations.

Further, the ordering of the results should be unique for the implementation.

To achieve this I have tried using

```
ORDER BY CASE 
WHEN Faculty = [faculty 1] then 0
WHEN Faculty = [faculty 2] then 1
...
WHEN Faculty = [faculty n] then n-1
```

However, this implementation doesn't seem to as intended when some faculties don't have any registrations.

I suspect an outer self join may help to retrieve values of 0, and this may fix the ORDER BY CASE problem.

Comment: Outer join a table/cte containing all faculties.

Comment: When clear this will be a faq. Please before considering posting read your textbook and/or manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to select from two tables in MySQL even if not all rows in one table have corespondents in the other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3969452/how-to-select-from-two-tables-in-mysql-even-if-not-all-rows-in-one-table-have-co)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a list of faculty members.  Let me assume that you have a separate table:

```
SELECT f.Faculty, COUNT(r.Faculty) 
FROM Faculty f LEFT JOIN
     Registrations r
     ON f.Faculty = r.Faculty
GROUP BY f.Faculty;
```