# To display 'NA' if the value is not available

Tags: sql, oracle, join, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have this piece of code to display resortid, resort name, manager name and his phone number along with a condition to display 'NA' against manager name and phone number if it is not available.

```
 select r.resortid, r.resortname, nvl(m.name, 'NA') as managername, nvl(m.phone, 'NA') as phoneno 
 from resort r inner join manager m 
 on r.managerid = m.managerid
 order by r.resortid;
```

The result of this code gives me the expected, but the row of 'NA' is not being displayed. Is the "NVL" keyword used, wrong there? Since it is Oracle SQL I used that keyword. Please suggest if its wrong anywhere. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to select from two tables in MySQL even if not all rows in one table have corespondents in the other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3969452/how-to-select-from-two-tables-in-mysql-even-if-not-all-rows-in-one-table-have-co)

Comment: (Clearly,) This is a faq. Please before considering posting read your textbook and/or manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code in table format. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's no manager, no row. Why? Because you joined those table. Should have **OUTER** joined them, i.e.

```
from resort r left join manager m on ...
```

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d4e42d/3)

As [littlefoot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9097906/littlefoot) mentioned, you should be using **LEFT JOIN** instead of **INNER JOIN**.

The **LEFT JOIN** keyword returns all records from the left table (resort), and the matched records from the right table (manager). The result is NA from the right side, if there is no match.

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
create table resort
(
  resortid char(5), 
  resortname varchar(25),
  managerid char(5)
 );
 
 create table manager
(
  managerid char(5), 
  name varchar(25),
  phone char(7)
 );
 
 
insert into resort values('r1', 'Resort 1', 'm1');
insert into resort values('r2', 'Resort 2', 'm2');
insert into manager values('m1', 'R.Manager One', '001-123');
```

**Query 1**:

```
select r.resortid, r.resortname, nvl(m.name, 'NA') as managername, nvl(m.phone, 'NA') as phoneno 
  from resort r left outer join manager m 
  on r.managerid = m.managerid
  order by r.resortid
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d4e42d/3/0)**:

```
| RESORTID | RESORTNAME |   MANAGERNAME | PHONENO |
|----------|------------|---------------|---------|
|    r1    |   Resort 1 | R.Manager One | 001-123 |
|    r2    |   Resort 2 |            NA |      NA |
```