# MySql update selection if column is null in one request

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

I have a SQL database with 2 tables and I need to get this data in **ONE REQUEST** to the server.

I am trying to get the `startDate`, `endDate`, and `title` data from the `event` table

Then I am also trying to get the `source` and `eventId` data from the `photo` table

So far, i have this which works perfect, but there's one problem.

```
SELECT event.startDate, event.endDate, event.id, event.title, photo.source, photo.eventId FROM event, photo 
WHERE event.id = 'UNIQUE ID NUMBER' AND photo.eventId = 'UNIQUE ID NUMBER';
```

Sometimes, the `photo.eventId` is equal to `NULL` meaning that nothing will return. If this is the case, the only data I need is data from the first table `event` which is the three columns `startDate`, `endDate`, and `title`

The return should then have the same output as this:

```
SELECT event.startDate, event.endDate, event.id, event.title FROM event WHERE event.id = 'UNIQUE ID NUMBER';
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to select from two tables in MySQL even if not all rows in one table have corespondents in the other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3969452/how-to-select-from-two-tables-in-mysql-even-if-not-all-rows-in-one-table-have-co)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you describe is the definition of a `LEFT` join of `event` to `photo`:

```
SELECT e.startDate, e.endDate, e.id, e.title, 
       p.source, p.eventId 
FROM event e LEFT JOIN photo p 
ON p.eventId = e.id 
WHERE e.id = 'UNIQUE ID NUMBER';
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to cheat this using by combining the two statements with `UNION` with the code below and then adding two extra `NULL` coumns to my second statement. This allows both table's data to be shown

```
SELECT event.startDate, event.endDate, event.id, event.title, photo.source, photo.eventId FROM event, photo 
WHERE event.id = 'UNIQUE ID NUMBER' AND photo.eventId = 'UNIQUE ID NUMBER' 
UNION SELECT event.startDate, event.endDate, event.id, event.title, null, null FROM event WHERE event.id = 'UNIQUE ID NUMBER';
```

Comment: This will return the matching rows of the 2 tables twice: once with the matching column of `photo` and again with nulls for the last 2 columns.

Answer (score 0):

If we use a `left join` the results from the table **event** will be returned, even if there are no matching records in **photo**.
NB I have modified the `WHERE` so as to show the results of both cases: matching and non-matching.
If there are more than one line in **photo** for an event we will get one row per photo. In that case you should look at using `STRING_AGG()` for the fields from **photo** and `GROUP BY` the fields from **event**.

> ```
> create TABLE event(
> startDate date,
> endDate date,
> id int, 
> title varchar(25)
>   );
> create table photo(
>   source varchar(25),
>   eventID int
>   );
> insert into event (id, title) values (1, 'event one'),(2,'event two');
> insert into photo values('source 1',1);
> ```

> ```
> SELECT 
>   event.startDate, 
>   event.endDate, 
>   event.id, 
>   event.title, 
>   photo.source, 
>   photo.eventId 
> FROM event
> LEFT JOIN photo 
> ON event.id = photo.eventId 
> WHERE event.id = 1 or event.id = 2;
> ```
>
> ```
> startDate | endDate | id | title     | source   | eventId
> :-------- | :------ | -: | :-------- | :------- | ------:
> null      | null    |  1 | event one | source 1 |       1
> null      | null    |  2 | event two | null     |    null
> ```

> ```
> SELECT event.startDate, event.endDate, event.id, event.title, photo.source, photo.eventId FROM event, photo 
> WHERE (event.id = 1 AND photo.eventId = 1)
> or (event.id = 2 AND photo.eventId = 2);
> ```
>
> ```
> startDate | endDate | id | title     | source   | eventId
> :-------- | :------ | -: | :-------- | :------- | ------:
> null      | null    |  1 | event one | source 1 |       1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=ca61045a67a04430cca453cfac6b2ad7)*