# MYSQL not getting the sum zero values (having no entries of that id) against distinct id of another table

Tags: mysql, sql, join

```sql
SELECT d.millid, d.bookno, d.partyname, d.count, 
       d.counttype, d.orderqty, d.dispqty, d.pending 
from ( SELECT b.millid, b.count, b.counttype, b.bookno, b.partyname, 
              COALESCE(b.bags,0) as orderqty, 
              COALESCE(sum(y.bags),0) as dispqty, 
              COALESCE((b.bags-sum(y.bags)),0) as pending 
       from yarnDispatch y 
       JOIN yarnbook b ON b.bookno=y.bookno 
       GROUP by b.bookno) d 
WHERE d.pending>0 
ORDER BY d.millid, d.bookno
```

In this query, table yarnbook is master table, having unique bookno (Booking Nos) from 1 to 2600 (and on) and other table yarndispatch have several or zero dispatch (bags) entries against the each of the same bookno (yarnbook).

When I'm running this query, giving the correct result where there is atleast single dispatch entry against bookno, but not giving (sum(bags) as 0) where there is no entry of dispatch in yarndispatch table.

Please share your views/solution.

Comment: `.. FROM yarnbook LEFT JOIN yarnDispatch ..`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to select from two tables in MySQL even if not all rows in one table have corespondents in the other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3969452/how-to-select-from-two-tables-in-mysql-even-if-not-all-rows-in-one-table-have-co)

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]. [ask] [Help] When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. Research before considering asking & reflect research in a question. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097)

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform an outer join, which preserves data in the case where one table has data and the other table does not, instead of an inner join which only returns rows if data is present in both tables.

Saying `JOIN` is equivalent to `INNER JOIN`. Replace `JOIN` with `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and your results should be more in line with what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You need a `LEFT JOIN` or `RIGHT JOIN`  to get the "empty" rows

```
SELECT d.millid, d.bookno, d.partyname, d.count, 
       d.counttype, d.orderqty, d.dispqty, d.pending 
from ( SELECT b.millid, b.count, b.counttype, b.bookno, b.partyname, 
              COALESCE(b.bags,0) as orderqty, 
              COALESCE(sum(IFNULL(y.bags,)),0) as dispqty, 
              COALESCE((b.bags-sum(y.bags)),0) as pending 
       from yarnDispatch y 
       RIGHT JOIN yarnbook b ON b.bookno=y.bookno 
       GROUP by b.bookno) d 
WHERE d.pending>0 
ORDER BY d.millid, d.bookno
```

Both joins are interchangeble but some peolple prefer `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT d.millid, d.bookno, d.partyname, d.count, 
       d.counttype, d.orderqty, d.dispqty, d.pending 
from ( SELECT b.millid, b.count, b.counttype, b.bookno, b.partyname, 
              COALESCE(b.bags,0) as orderqty, 
              COALESCE(sum(IFNULL(y.bags,0)),0) as dispqty, 
              COALESCE((b.bags-sum(y.bags)),0) as pending 
       from
       yarnbook b 
        LEFT JOIN yarnDispatch y ON b.bookno=y.bookno 
       GROUP by b.bookno) d 
WHERE d.pending>0 
ORDER BY d.millid, d.bookno
```

Comment: *but some peolple prefer LEFT JOIN* Some DBMSs (for example, SQLite) does not support RIGHT JOIN.

Comment: sqllite needs a lot more code, that is nothing new

Comment: Only some people? I'd say most people find `main table left join optional data` much easier to understand than `optional data right join main table`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your valuable reply;

I've tried following query and it is working;

```
    SELECT
    d.millid,
    d.bookno,
    d.partyname,
    d.count,
    d.counttype,
    d.orderqty,
    d.dispqty,
    (d.orderqty - d.dispqty) AS pending
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        b.millid,
        b.count,
        b.counttype,
        b.bookno,
        b.partyname,
        COALESCE(b.bags, 0) AS orderqty,
        Y.bags,
        COALESCE(SUM(Y.bags),
        0) AS dispqty
    FROM
        yarnDispatch Y
    RIGHT JOIN yarnbook b ON
        b.bookno = Y.bookno
    GROUP BY
        b.bookno
    ORDER BY
        b.millid,
        b.bookno
) d
WHERE
    (d.orderqty - d.dispqty) > 0 
ORDER BY
    d.millid,
    d.bookno
```