# Process missing data while joining

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join, window-functions

Consider the query below

```
DECLARE @DateTimeStart DATETIME
DECLARE @DateTimeEnd DATETIME

SET @dateTimeStart = '2001-04-04'
SET @dateTimeEnd = '2001-04-06'

DECLARE @QH TABLE 
            (
                dt date, 
                QueueName varchar(10)
            )

INSERT INTO @QH (Dt, QueueName)
VALUES ('2001-04-04', 'Queue01'),
       ('2001-04-05', 'Queue01'),
       ('2001-04-06', 'Queue01'),
       ('2001-04-04', 'Queue02'),
       ('2001-04-05', 'Queue02'),
       ('2001-04-06', 'Queue02')

-- SELECT * FROM @QH

DECLARE @SNH TABLE
             (
                 dt date, 
                 QueueName varchar(10),
                 SN varchar(10)
             )

INSERT INTO @SNH (Dt, QueueName, SN)
VALUES ('2001-04-04', 'Queue01', 'Q01SN01'),
       ('2001-04-05', 'Queue01', 'Q01SN01'),
       ('2001-04-06', 'Queue01', 'Q01SN01'),
       ('2001-04-04', 'Queue02', 'Q02SN01'),
       ('2001-04-05', 'Queue02', 'Q02SN01'),
       ('2001-04-06', 'Queue02', 'Q02SN02')

-- SELECT * FROM @SNH

SELECT
    MIN(QHCore.dt) clnStartDate, 
    MAX(QHCore.dt) clnEndDate, 
    QHCore.QueueName AS clnQueueName, 
    SNHStart.SN AS clnSNStart, 
    SNHEnd.SN AS clnSNEnd
FROM    
    @QH QHCore, @QH QHStart, @QH QHEnd, @SNH SNHStart, @SNH SNHEnd
WHERE
    QHCore.QueueName = QHStart.QueueName
    AND QHCore.QueueName = QHEnd.QueueName
    AND QHCore.QueueName = SNHStart.QueueName
    AND QHCore.QueueName = SNHEnd.QueueName
    AND SNHStart.dt = @DateTimeStart
    AND SNHEnd.dt = @DateTimeEnd
GROUP BY 
    QHCore.QueueName, SNHStart.SN, SNHEnd.SN
```

When `@DateTimeStart` and `@DateTimeEnd` matches those existing in @SNH table, it selects into nice looking table,

| clnStartDate | clnEndDate | clnQueueName | clnSNStart | clnSNEnd |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2001-04-04 | 2001-04-06 | Queue01 | Q01SN01 | Q01SN01 |
| 2001-04-04 | 2001-04-06 | Queue02 | Q02SN01 | Q02SN02 |

but what if there's no corresponding entry in @SNH as below

```
insert into @SNH(Dt, QueueName, SN)
values
--('2001-04-04','Queue01','Q01SN01'),
('2001-04-05','Queue01','Q01SN01'),
('2001-04-06','Queue01','Q01SN01'),
('2001-04-04','Queue02','Q02SN01'),
('2001-04-05','Queue02','Q02SN01'),
('2001-04-06','Queue02','Q02SN02')
```

then the entire line is not selected.

| clnStartDate | clnEndDate | clnQueueName | clnSNStart | clnSNEnd |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2001-04-04 | 2001-04-06 | Queue02 | Q02SN01 | Q02SN02 |

So, is there a way to Select into the resulting table empty value somehow?

For it to look as follows

| clnStartDate | clnEndDate | clnQueueName | clnSNStart | clnSNEnd |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2001-04-04 | 2001-04-06 | Queue01 | '' | Q01SN01 |
| 2001-04-04 | 2001-04-06 | Queue02 | Q02SN01 | Q02SN02 |

Comment: [Bad Habits to Kick : Using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)  It's an article from more then 10 years ago, but it still applies!

Comment: I'd personally suggest that the older it gets the *more* applicable it gets, @Luuk . The ANSI-89 syntax was still supported in some versions of SQL Server when that article was published; it's not supported in *any of them* now. The ANSI-92 syntax has now been around for **3 decades**, so there's no excuse to not being using it (ignorance is not an excuse any more).

Comment: [mre] [ask] [Help] Please read the edit help re formatting.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to select from two tables in MySQL even if not all rows in one table have corespondents in the other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3969452/how-to-select-from-two-tables-in-mysql-even-if-not-all-rows-in-one-table-have-co)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that a `LEFT` join of `@QH` to `@SNH` and window functions will do what you want.

It is not clear whether you want the date limits to be applied on both tables or just on `@SNH`.

If you want all the dates of `@QH`, even if they are not between the date limits:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       MIN(q.Dt) OVER (PARTITION BY q.QueueName) clnStartDate,
       MAX(q.Dt) OVER (PARTITION BY q.QueueName) clnEndDate,
       q.QueueName clnQueueName,    
       FIRST_VALUE(s.SN) OVER (PARTITION BY q.QueueName ORDER BY q.Dt) clnSNStart,
       FIRST_VALUE(s.SN) OVER (PARTITION BY q.QueueName ORDER BY q.Dt DESC) clnSNEnd
FROM @QH q LEFT JOIN @SNH s
ON s.QueueName = q.QueueName AND s.Dt = q.Dt
AND s.Dt BETWEEN @DateTimeStart AND @DateTimeEnd;
```

If you want to apply the limits to both tables:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       MIN(q.Dt) OVER (PARTITION BY q.QueueName) clnStartDate,
       MAX(q.Dt) OVER (PARTITION BY q.QueueName) clnEndDate,
       q.QueueName clnQueueName,    
       FIRST_VALUE(s.SN) OVER (PARTITION BY q.QueueName ORDER BY q.Dt) clnSNStart,
       FIRST_VALUE(s.SN) OVER (PARTITION BY q.QueueName ORDER BY q.Dt DESC) clnSNEnd
FROM @QH q LEFT JOIN @SNH s
ON s.QueueName = q.QueueName AND s.Dt = q.Dt
WHERE q.Dt BETWEEN @DateTimeStart AND @DateTimeEnd;
```