# MySql query Get all rows from left table and common from right table

Tags: mysql, join, left-join, right-join

Table 1 - [customer_kitchen_service_plans](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2bNCw.png) and data https://prnt.sc/00_ip7uWiQuq

Table 2 - [kitchen_service_plans_linking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6I1ZB.png) and data https://prnt.sc/e_GW64THTCFK

Above two are the tables and i want to join in such a way that it should return All the rows from Table 1 and Common rows from Table 2

Join using column `kitchen_service_plan_id` from Table 1 and `kitchen_service_plan_parent_id` from Table 2

Current query is as below

```sql
select * from `customer_kitchen_service_plans` as `cksp` 
left join `kitchen_service_plans_linking` as `kspl` on 
  `kspl`.`kitchen_service_plan_parent_id` = 
  `cksp`.`kitchen_service_plan_id` 
where `cksp`.`status` = 'ACTIVE' and `cksp`.`customer_id` = 2
```

Comment: 'If there is no matching row for the right table in the ON or USING part in a LEFT JOIN, a row with all columns set to NULL is used for the right table. You can use this fact to find rows in a table that have no counterpart in another table:' https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html

Comment: @RohitGupta It does not return rows from right table

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) [Why are images of text, code and mathematical expressions discouraged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320052/266284)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to select from two tables in MySQL even if not all rows in one table have corespondents in the other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3969452/how-to-select-from-two-tables-in-mysql-even-if-not-all-rows-in-one-table-have-co)

Comment: Please either ask about 1 bad query/function with the obligatory [mre] & why you think it should return something else at the 1st subexpression that it doesn't give what you expect, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do & ideally a [mre]. But please ask about the former 1st because misconceptions in the former will get in the way of understanding the latter. And bad code doesn't tell us what you wish it would do. [ask] [Help]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want a left outer join which returns all rows from the first table and  matching rows from the right.

```sql
select * from `customer_kitchen_service_plans` as cksp 
left outer join `kitchen_service_plans_linking` as kspl on 
  kspl.`kitchen_service_plan_parent_id` = 
  cksp.`kitchen_service_plan_id` 
where cksp.`status` = 'ACTIVE' and cksp.`customer_id` = 2
```

Here's a discussion on  [Left Outer Join in MySQL](https://dotnettutorials.net/lesson/left-outer-join-mysql//)

Comment: @RonakSolanki Please delete & flag obsolete comments. Please clarify via edits, not comments.

Answer (score 0):

See if that's help

```sql
SELECT * FROM customer_kitchen_service_plans 
LEFT JOIN kitchen_service_plans_linking ON 
          customer_kitchen_service_plans.kitchen_service_plan_id= 
          kitchen_service_plans_linking.kitchen_service_plan_parent_id;
```

Comment: Arman Hasan Siam and Rohit Gupta,
I have added my current query in the question