# Postgres: Select multiple but show records where linked field isn't present

Tags: postgresql, outer-join

I have multiple tables in my Postgres database that are linked by a field called `id`. My main table, `Person` is linked to other tables `Address`, `Phone` and`Email` by `id`.

This line of code gets information about the person from all tables in the database:

```
SELECT *
FROM "Person" p, "Address" a
WHERE p.id = a.id
```

This isn't showing rows where `p.id` exists, but we don't have an address for that specific person yet (`a.id != p.id` in any case).

How do I get the select statement to also return fields where `a.id` is not found to contain `p.id`?

Comment: It's a strange naming convention that the foreign key column in `"Address"` that references the `"Person"` table is named `id` as well. What is the primary key column named in `"Address"`?

Comment: I said it like that so it is more simple. The Address file actually has an id column named "id", and the linked record is "person"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to select from two tables in MySQL even if not all rows in one table have corespondents in the other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3969452/how-to-select-from-two-tables-in-mysql-even-if-not-all-rows-in-one-table-have-co)

Answer (score 0):

You want an outer join which can only be done by getting rid of the ancient, outdated and fragile implicit joins in the WHERE clause and use a proper JOIN operator:

```
select *
from "Person" p
  left join "Address" a on p.id = a.id;
```

Comment: Great. And if I wanted to mimic this for more than just one table, would it look like:
left join "Address" a on p.id = a.id, "Phone" ph on p.id = ph.id

Comment: "*can only be done by […] a proper JOIN operator*" - couldn't lateral subqueries also achieve this?