# MySQL to fill in the blanks with NULLs when their isn't a row based on set number of IDs from the join

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, join, outer-join

Looking to fill in the blanks with NULLs when there isn't a record that is for a row that I am expecting.

Consider the following

**wp_posts (p)**

| ID | post_title |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Week 1 |
| 2 | Week 2 |
| 3 | Week 3 |
| 4 | Week 4 |
| 5 | Week 5 |

**wp_users (u)**

| ID | user_email |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | email1@example.com |
| 2 | email2@example.com |
| 3 | email3@example.com |
| 4 | email4@example.com |
| 5 | email5@example.com |

**wp_learndash_user_activity (lua)**

| ID | user_id | post_id | activity_started | activity_complete |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1668733909 | 1668733979 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | 1668733909 | 1668733979 |
| 3 | 1 | 3 | 1668733909 | 1668733979 |
| 4 | 1 | 4 | 1668733909 | 1668733979 |
| 5 | 1 | 5 | 1668733909 | 1668733979 |
| 6 | 2 | 1 | 1668733909 | 1668733979 |
| 7 | 2 | 2 | 1668733909 | 1668733979 |
| 8 | 2 | 3 | 1668733909 | 1668733979 |
| 9 | 2 | 4 | 1668733909 | 1668733979 |
| 10 | 3 | 1 | 1668733909 | 1668733979 |
| 11 | 3 | 2 | 1668733909 | 1668733979 |

I have written this SQL

```
SELECT u.user_email AS user_email, p.post_title AS lesson_title, DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(lua.activity_started), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') AS activity_started, DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(lua.activity_completed), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') AS activity_completed
FROM wp_learndash_user_activity lua
JOIN wp_users u ON u.ID = lua.user_id
JOIN wp_posts p ON p.ID = lua.post_id
WHERE lua.post_id IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
ORDER BY u.ID ASC
```

Which gives these results

| user_email | lesson_title | activity_started | activity_completed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| email1@example.com | Week 1 | 2022-11-18 01:11:49 | 2022-11-18 01:12:59 |
| email1@example.com | Week 2 | 2022-11-18 01:11:49 | 2022-11-18 01:12:59 |
| email1@example.com | Week 3 | 2022-11-18 01:11:49 | 2022-11-18 01:12:59 |
| email1@example.com | Week 4 | 2022-11-18 01:11:49 | 2022-11-18 01:12:59 |
| email1@example.com | Week 5 | 2022-11-18 01:11:49 | 2022-11-18 01:12:59 |
| email2@example.com | Week 1 | 2022-11-18 01:11:49 | 2022-11-18 01:12:59 |
| email2@example.com | Week 2 | 2022-11-18 01:11:49 | 2022-11-18 01:12:59 |
| email2@example.com | Week 3 | 2022-11-18 01:11:49 | 2022-11-18 01:12:59 |
| email2@example.com | Week 4 | 2022-11-18 01:11:49 | 2022-11-18 01:12:59 |
| email3@example.com | Week 1 | 2022-11-18 01:11:49 | 2022-11-18 01:12:59 |
| email3@example.com | Week 2 | 2022-11-18 01:11:49 | 2022-11-18 01:12:59 |

However, what I would really like is for it to show 5 rows for all users. That means if they did not have entries for the 5 posts (lua.post_id IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)) then they would still show the user_email and lesson_title but show NULL for activity_started and activity_complete

See the following for the desired results.

| user_email | lesson_title | activity_started | activity_completed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| email1@example.com | Week 1 | 2022-11-18 01:11:49 | 2022-11-18 01:12:59 |
| email1@example.com | Week 2 | 2022-11-18 01:11:49 | 2022-11-18 01:12:59 |
| email1@example.com | Week 3 | 2022-11-18 01:11:49 | 2022-11-18 01:12:59 |
| email1@example.com | Week 4 | 2022-11-18 01:11:49 | 2022-11-18 01:12:59 |
| email1@example.com | Week 5 | 2022-11-18 01:11:49 | 2022-11-18 01:12:59 |
| email2@example.com | Week 1 | 2022-11-18 01:11:49 | 2022-11-18 01:12:59 |
| email2@example.com | Week 2 | 2022-11-18 01:11:49 | 2022-11-18 01:12:59 |
| email2@example.com | Week 3 | 2022-11-18 01:11:49 | 2022-11-18 01:12:59 |
| email2@example.com | Week 4 | NULL | NULL |
| email2@example.com | Week 5 | NULL | NULL |
| email3@example.com | Week 1 | 2022-11-18 01:11:49 | 2022-11-18 01:12:59 |
| email3@example.com | Week 2 | 2022-11-18 01:11:49 | 2022-11-18 01:12:59 |
| email3@example.com | Week 3 | NULL | NULL |
| email3@example.com | Week 4 | NULL | NULL |
| email3@example.com | Week 5 | NULL | NULL |

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to select from two tables in MySQL even if not all rows in one table have corespondents in the other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3969452/how-to-select-from-two-tables-in-mysql-even-if-not-all-rows-in-one-table-have-co)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To combine each **user** with each **post** use [CROSS JOIN](https://www.w3schools.com/mysql/mysql_join_cross.asp).
And then [LEFT JOIN](https://www.w3schools.com/mysql/mysql_join_left.asp) to matching lesson_user_activity

```sql
SELECT u.user_email AS user_email,
    p.post_title AS lesson_title,
    DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(lua.activity_started), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') AS activity_started,
    DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(lua.activity_completed), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') AS activity_completed
FROM wp_users u
    CROSS JOIN wp_posts p
    LEFT JOIN wp_learndash_user_activity lua
        ON u.ID = lua.user_id AND p.ID = lua.post_id
WHERE p.ID IN (1,2,3,4,5)
ORDER BY u.ID ASC, p.ID ASC
```

Comment: That looks interesting but I think the one part it is missing is restricting either the p.ID or lua.post_id to the required input.
Perhaps if I add WHERE p.ID IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

Comment: @BobbyS
My mistake. I have updated answer. lua.post_id IN (1,2,3,4,5) does not work, because it might be NULL.