# Full outer join with all rows from second table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, left-join, sql-server-2016

I have following table.

[image: Table]

Here, for a candidate, I have rows for either higher, post-grad, or both types of education.
I am looking for a result that will have an additional row where the candidate is missing either higher or post-grad education.

[image]

I can address this by checking which candidates have missing qualifications and a dummy row for it. I am, however, trying to see if I can use a dummy qualification table and do some sort of full outer join or outer apply to get the expected result.

Code to help:

```
drop table if exists #candidate

create table #candidate
(
row_id int
,candidate_ref varchar(10)  
,qualification_type varchar(30)
,university_name varchar(30)
)

drop table if exists #dummytable

create table #dummytable
(
row_id int
,qualification_type varchar(30)
)

insert into #candidate
select 1, 'a',  'Higher Eduation'   ,'University X'      union
select 1, 'a',  'Higher Eduation'   ,'University Y'      union
select 1, 'a',  'Postgrad Education'    ,'University Y'  union
select 1, 'b',  'Higher Eduation'   ,'University U'      union
select 1, 'c',  'Higher Eduation'   ,'University 1'      union
select 1, 'c',  'Postgrad Education'    ,'University 1'  union
select 1, 'd',  'Postgrad Education'    ,'University C'  

insert into #dummytable
select 1, 'Higher Eduation' union
select 1, 'Postgrad Education'
```

I am open to have additional dummy key column (for example row_id = 1 for both tables) to enable full outer join.

Comment: You need a separate table of all possible `candidate-ref`, do you have one? Really your `#candidate` table should realy be called `#candidate_qualification` with two foreign keys.

Comment: @Charlieface yes I do have a table for all candidate_refs. Not sure how this will help though.

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to select from two tables in MySQL even if not all rows in one table have corespondents in the other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3969452/how-to-select-from-two-tables-in-mysql-even-if-not-all-rows-in-one-table-have-co)

Comment: @philipxy - just wondering what is the easy way to show table data inside the post. In my post I have codes (not as image) and images of how the table data looks and expected result.

Comment: Cut & paste code input format in columns. Cut & paste output as text. Then images are redundant & can differ from what was actually run. There is a markdown table format whose displayed text can be cut & pasted, but  the pre-displayed text has other characters. Not giving exact input & output for a [mre] can introduce differences between what was run & what is in a post. PS Please use minimal representative data.

Comment: There is no question in this post. It's not clear what is input/given or how the desired result is a function of that. "where the candidate is missing either" from where, and do you mean in the output or input? "checking which' & "see if I can use" & "have additional dummy key column" are not clear. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. PS Requirements dumps are off-topic. How are you stuck? What parts can you do? [ask] [Help] [mre] PS You mention full join, why not left join, if you want all rows of only one table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your tables are not really normalized properly. The `#candidate` table is really a `#candidate_qualifications` and you should have a separate `#candidate` tabel of all unique candidates.

Now you just cross-join the two parent tables, then left-join the link table

```sql
SELECT
  c.candidate_ref,
  q.qualification_type,
  cq.university_name
FROM #candidate c
CROSS JOIN #qualifications q
LEFT JOIN #candidate_qualifications cq
  ON cq.candidate_ref = c.candidate_ref
 AND cq.qualification_type = q.qualification_type;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/zphSlpGm)