# find data that couldn't exist working with 2 tables

Tags: sql, left-join

3 tables:

```
IMAGES [IDim, title, descr, etc.]
USERS [IDus, name, surname, etc.]
OPERATION [ID, IDim, IDus, status, reserveDate, etc.]
```

I need a query that gets all rows of IMAGES and adds the `status` read from the OPERATION table.
The `status` field gets value `'READY'` or `'LOST'` only sometimes (and in that moment a link between the IMAGES and the OPERATION tables is created).

I tried this incomplete and wrong query:

```
SELECT i.IDim, i.title, i.descr, o.status
FROM IMAGES AS i, OPERATION AS o
WHERE i.IDim = o.IDim
```

This fetches only the ones in the OPERATION table, but It's possible that some images are not inserted there.

A possibility is to create a reference in OPERATION every time a new item is inserted in IMAGES, setting the `status` field as `'NONE'`, for example, but I'd like to avoid it.

How do I write this?

Comment: [How to select from two tables in MySQL even if not all rows in one table have corespondents in the other?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3969452/3404097)

Comment: (Clearly) Your errors & goal will be faqs. Please before considering posting: Pin down code issues via [mre]. Read manuals/references & google error messages & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. SO/SE search is poor & literal & unusual, read the help. Google re googling/searching, including Q&A at [meta] & [meta.se]. [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help] Reflect research in posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a LEFT JOIN for that.

JOINs are around for 30 years now, you should really start using them all the time

```
SELECT i.IDim, i.title, i.descr, o.status
FROM IMAGES AS i
 LEFT JOIN OPERATION AS o
ON i.IDim = o.IDim
```

Comment: Thanks. I understood that I must improve my basic SQL knowledge.