# Summarising data including zeros for where no data exists

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, left-join, aggregate-functions

I have a table containing a list of years, from 2010 onwards, along the lines of.

```
CREATE TABLE Years
(
    YearName int
);
    
INSERT INTO Years (YearName)
VALUES
    (2010), (2011), (2012), (2013),
    (2014), (2015), (2016), (2017),
    (2018), (2019), (2020), (2021),
    (2022), (2023), (2024), (2025)
```

I have a second table containing people, along the lines of

```
CREATE TABLE People
(
    PersonID int PRIMARY KEY, 
    PersonName varchar(50)
);
    
INSERT INTO People (PersonID, PersonName)
VALUES
    (1, 'Bob'),
    (2, 'Kate'),
    (3, 'Jo'),
    (4, 'Fred');
```

And I have a table containing the work that people have done, of various types each year:

```
CREATE TABLE Workload
(
    ID int PRIMARY KEY, 
    PersonID int, 
    YearName int, 
    WorkType varchar(8), 
    Hours int
);
    
INSERT INTO Workload (ID, PersonID, YearName, WorkType, Hours)
VALUES
    (1, 1, 2014, 'Plumbing', 7),
    (2, 1, 2020, 'Washing', 9),
    (3, 1, 2020, 'Cooking', 10),
    (4, 1, 2020, 'Drawing', 4),
    (5, 1, 2021, 'Reading', 2),
    (6, 2, 2020, 'Washing', 9),
    (7, 2, 2021, 'Cooking', 10),
    (8, 2, 2022, 'Drawing', 4),
    (9, 3, 2014, 'Cooking', 4),
    (10, 3, 2014, 'Plumbing', 22),
    (11, 3, 2015, 'Washing', 7);
```

I want to summarise the total amount of work done by each person, per year. So, I've got this as my starting point:

```
SELECT 
    PersonName, YearName, SUM(Hours) AS WorkDone
FROM 
    People p 
INNER JOIN 
    Workload w ON p.PersonID = w.PersonID
WHERE 
    YearName BETWEEN YEAR(GETDATE()) - 9 AND YEAR(GETDATE())
GROUP BY 
    PersonName, YearName
```

This works fine, but what I'd like to have is an output that gives a zero value for each person in each year where they did none of these tasks:

| Person | Year | Workload |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Bob | 2014 | 7 |
| Bob | 2015 | 0 |
| Bob | 2016 | 0 |
| Bob | 2017 | 0 |
| Bob | 2018 | 0 |
| Bob | 2019 | 0 |
| Bob | 2020 | 23 |
| Bob | 2021 | 0 |
| Bob | 2022 | 0 |
| Bob | 2023 | 0 |
| Kate | 2014 | 0 |
| Kate | 2015 | 0 |
| Kate | 2016 | 0 |
| Kate | 2017 | 0 |
| Kate | 2018 | 0 |
| Kate | 2019 | 0 |
| Kate | 2020 | 9 |
| Kate | 2021 | 10 |
| Kate | 2022 | 4 |
| Kate | 2023 | 0 |

... and so on for the other people and years.

How do I best achieve this? I sense that I probably need to cross apply the three tables, but can't seem to figure out how to do so and get the results I need.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to select from two tables in MySQL even if not all rows in one table have corespondents in the other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3969452/how-to-select-from-two-tables-in-mysql-even-if-not-all-rows-in-one-table-have-co)

Comment: Thanks for your comments @philipxy. I did indeed do some searching before posting, and read the suggestions produced by SO before submitting my questions.  I wasn't aware that I was using Markdown tables for any code, just to display the output I was expecting. I tried to create an example using sqlfiddle, but it was not working for me yesterday. The question to which you post a link does not answer my question, as it is based on 2 tables which are related, whereas mine needs to draw on two unrelated table (years and people) plus a a related one (workload). But thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could `cross join` the years and people table to generate all possible combinations, then bring the workload table with a `LEFT JOIN` - which ensures that "missing" years/people tuples are not filtered out. The final step is aggregation, and `COALESCE()` to return `0` on unmatched tuples.

```
SELECT p.PersonName, y.YearName, COALESCE(SUM(w.Hours), 0) as WorkDone
FROM People p 
CROSS JOIN Years y
LEFT JOIN Workload w ON w.PersonID = p.PersonID AND w.YearName = y.YearName
WHERE y.YearName BETWEEN YEAR(GetDate())-9 AND YEAR(GETDATE())
GROUP BY p.PersonID, p.PersonName, y.YearName
ORDER BY p.PersonName, y.YearName
```

Note that it is safer to include the person id in the `group by` clause; two different persons might have the same name, and you probably don't want their workloads to be grouped together.

We could also use a correlated subquery (or `apply`) to do the workload computation, which would avoid outer aggregation:

```
SELECT p.PersonName, y.YearName, w.*
FROM People p 
CROSS JOIN Years y
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT COALESCE(SUM(w.Hours), 0) as WorkDone
    FROM Workload w 
    WHERE w.PersonID = p.PersonID AND w.YearName = y.YearName
) w
WHERE y.YearName BETWEEN YEAR(GetDate())-9 AND YEAR(GETDATE())
ORDER BY p.PersonName, y.YearName
```

Comment: Thanks - that's really helpful. I've gone for the second method you suggest. Can I ask one follow-up? If I want to restrict this to show all years (including those with zero work) but only for those staff who've done some work at some time (there are many people who've never done any work in any year) how would I do that?

Comment: @AndrewRichards: that would likely require another level of nesting (or another join)... that's probably worth [a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)

Answer (score 0):

By using this query, the minimum year of each person is extracted and based on the non-existent days, a value of zero is set

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/rpmPRQ3c)

```
;with _list as (

select *
        from (
                SELECT 
PersonName, YearName,sum(w.Hours) over(partition by p.PersonID,YearName) as Workload
                ,row_number() over(partition by p.PersonID,YearName order by  p.PersonID) as rw
                ,min(YearName) over(partition by p.PersonID order by  p.PersonID) as minYearName
                --, SUM(Hours) as WorkDone
                FROM People p 
                INNER JOIN Workload w ON p.PersonID=w.PersonID

        )a
        where a.rw=1  
)
select  
ISNULL(a.PersonName,b.PersonName) as PersonName ,b.YearName
,ISNULL(a.Workload,b.Workload) as Workload
from (
        select a.PersonName,b.YearName,0 Workload
        from Years b
        cross join (
                select PersonName,min(minYearName) as minYearName
                from _list
                group by PersonName
        )a
        where b.YearName between a.minYearName and  DATEPART(YEAR ,GETDATE())
)b
left join  _list a on  a.YearName=b.YearName 
and  a.PersonName=b.PersonName
```