# postgres join get data from left table only if no matching found in right table and get matching data also

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, left-join

Input:

contract_para

```
Id
1
2
3
4
5
```

contract_lines

```
Id   |  para_id
1    |  1
2    |  2
3    |  3
```

Output:

```
contract_para_id    | contract_lines_id     |   contract_lines_para_id
1                   | 1                     |   1
2                   | 2                     |   2
3                   | 3                     |   3
4                   | null                  |   null
5                   | null                  |   null
```

How do I join two tables and return matching data and also return data in the first table and not in second?

Comment: Could you please edit your question and share your simple data / expected output as text ? so it can be easy to reproduce your problem !

Comment: what you are looking for is a contract_para left outer join contract_lines. Please search for outer join in here ... https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-join.html

Comment: @Niranjan, can you please post the query you tried ?

Comment: Hi @NandalalSeth  SELECT cp.id, cl.para_id 
FROM negotiation.contract_para cp
LEFT OUTER JOIN negotiation.contract_lines cl
ON cp.id = cl.para_id

Comment: The title & body ask for different things.

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Please either ask re 1 bad query/function with obligatory [mre], including why you think it should return something else or are unsure at the 1st subexpression that you get what you expect or are stuck, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do with justification & a [mre--then misunderstood code doesn't belong. But please ask about unexpected behaviour 1st because misconceptions get in the way of your goal. [ask] [Help] Basic questions are faqs.

Comment: (Clearly) When clear this will be a faq. Please before considering posting: Pin down code issues via [mre]. Read manuals/references & google error messages & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. SO/SE search is poor & literal & unusual, read the help. Google re googling/searching, including Q&A at [meta] & [meta.se]. [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help] Reflect research in posts.

Comment: [How to select from two tables in MySQL even if not all rows in one table have corespondents in the other?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3969452/3404097)

Answer (score -1):

This will retrieves rows from **contract_para** (`from contract_para`) even if there are no matching rows in **contract_lines** (`left join contract_lines`) :

```
select *
from contract_para cp
left join contract_lines cl on cp.id = cl.para_id
```

Comment: Hi @SelVazi, above query I  tried it returns only matched data but i want non matching data from left table also

Comment: It returns the expected output, You can try it here : https://dbfiddle.uk/GXHbXTf1

Answer (score -1):

Left outer join will work here :

Refer :

```
select *
from contract_para c_para
left join contract_lines c_lines on c_para.id = c_lines.para_id
```